# How can batch include both positive and negative labels?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I have pedestrian classification problem which I want to solve with VGG-16. In order to do that, I prepared train and test sets. My train set has 2038 images and my test set has 252 images. My batch size is 64. How can I tell Keras that I want these 64 images to include both positive and negative labels while training? I don't want it to learn only on positive or only on negative labels.

Comment: Since there is methods like SGD, I don't think it is a huge problem to have some minibatch contain only one label.  That said, since keras's `fit` does not take care of it, you probably need to write your own data generator like this https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly.

Comment: What makes you think that this will be a problem and you need to do something about it?

Comment: if your positive and negative labels are balanced, it is very unlicky that your batch contain only positive or only negative (but can happen).

Answer (score 1):

If you shuffle your training data (which is strongly recommended), there is a very small chance to get all the 64 samples belonging to the same class. For the two-class task there should be no problem with the data.

However, if you wish to guarantee balanced training batches, you can use third-party code like [BalancedBatchGenerator](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/imblearn.keras.BalancedBatchGenerator.html#imblearn.keras.BalancedBatchGenerator). See this [tutorial](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/applications/porto_seguro_keras_under_sampling.html) for further information.